# EditText как изменить цвет подчеркиваня?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть разметка с `EditText`, и у `EditText` почему-то розовая полоса подчеркивания :)). Я порылся в гугле, но ничего толкового там не подсказали (или возникали ошибки, или попросту не работало). В приложении стоит тема `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Как можно изменить цвет этого подчеркивания на другой?)

Comment: Пробовали `colorAccent` в стилях менять?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, о! Сработало! Закиньте в ответ.

Comment: Уже есть хороший ответ. Главное помнить, что эти аттрибуты много на что влияют. и ими надо аккуратно пользоваться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В стилях:

Отвечает за нижний контрол ("полоса подчеркивания")

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Любой цвет</item>
```

Отвечает за ползунок:

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/Любой цвет</item>
```

Или как уже написали в комментариях, colorAccent будет менять цвет всех контролов для данного стиля.
Можете использовать theme editor, там очень наглядно видны эти изменения.

Comment: Главное учитывать, что эти аттрибуты, будучи в основной теме повлияют не только на EditText, но и ещё на всякое. Если не ошибаюсь, то, например, на цвет выделения элементов в NavigationView. Так что лучше отдельную тему создать для EditText и её в стиле основном назначить или прямо в разметке.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Если честно самый лучший способ, чтоб не нарушать концепцию Material Design, изменить colorAccent. Просто есть возможность изменить детально нужные элементы, я их показал и это соответствует вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно так:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

`themes.xml`:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">#5D36A3</item>  <!-- Отвечает за ползунок -->

<item name="colorAccent">#5D36A3</item>  <!-- Отвечает за подчёркивание -->
```